# Asp.net MVC Identity In Area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

im begginer in asp.net MVC 
and i have one question

in my project , i have two Area : Admin & User

and in Project root controller i have Account Controller ,and my question is

in account controller for change password should called

```
    // GET: /Account/Manage
    public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
```

but in my area for change password i call this url

```
/User/Profile
```

I want to know, for this scenario ,What should I do?
must for every area create account controller ?
or i can access from `/User/Profile/ to /Account/Manage` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should have only one `Account` controller, by default every unauthorized request will redirect to `/Account/Login`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
   });            
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

The only thing that you should do is to decorating your controllers in your areas with `Authorize` attribute.